# How can I access elements of a list within a list?

Tags: python, list, element

So I wanted to retrieve certain values of an element of a list within a list without having to loop. For example, what would I do if I wanted to retrieve the value "no" from the second element of the variable message.

```
message=[[0," "],[1,"yes","no","maybe"]]
```

I know that message[1] would give me:

```
[1,"yes","no","maybe"]
```

In addition, I'm also aware of the fact I could store the value of message[1] to a new variable and access that value using the above technique:

```
list=message[1]
print (list[2])
```

However, I was wondering if there was a more clean and simple method I'm not aware of:

Comment: `message[1][2]` is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> message=[[0," "],[1,"yes","no","maybe"]]
>>> message[1][2]
'no'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it conceptually.

You already have stated that you know that message[1] returns

```
[1,"yes","no","maybe"]
```

Which is itself another list.

Since you know how to select elements from a list, it's the exact same process. You just select the item within that second returned list with another set of brackets and the place of the element.

Since you asked:

```
>>> message[1][2]
```

is what you are looking for.

It is in essence saying:

```
>>> [1,"yes","no","maybe"][2]
```

This can be expanded continually until you reach an element which is not a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I like `operator.itemgetter`

```
>>> import operator
>>> one = operator.itemgetter(1)
>>> two = operator.itemgetter(2)
>>> message=[[0," "],[1,"yes","no","maybe"]]
>>> two(one(message))
'no'
>>>
```